# Firebase Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented Firebase for push notification in my Android app. I implemented two services for register the token and for create the notification when it is detected. When my app is launch it's working but when my app is closed it doesn't working.

```
public class FirebaseinstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e("Firebase", refreshedToken);
        MainActivity.setFirebaseToken(refreshedToken);
    }

}

public class MyFirebaseMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    //It is same as we did in earlier posts
    private void sendNotification(Map<String, String> notification) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(notification.get("title"))
            .setContentText(notification.get("body"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

         NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And my manifest :

```
    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseinstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessageService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And my request :

```
{
    "to": "ex1CtVz5bbE:APA91bHiM_BCun62A9iCobF1yV26Dwn-hYCDhkYPoWEG5ZdqH0P28UsE5q1v7QibwAX7AJ290-9en9L6f548_2b7WEbJ8RPEWlIotLczjjCP7xEOWqeJk6Iz44vilWYvdu4chPwfsvXD",
    "data": {
        "title": "Notification",
        "body": "Message",
    }
}
```

I already found a few solutions in StackOverflow but it doesn't work in my case. I have an API Rest which call the API Request Post : https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

So, there is my question : Does Firebase handle push notification when the app is closed and how to ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Can you also specify the *StackOverflow* solutions you've tried and didn't work? It would help narrow down what's causing this.

Comment: In the api call the parameters can be notification object or data object i tried with both and it doesn't work.

Comment: Add your manifest.xml

Comment: don't try with both. Use only `data`

Comment: Yes Tim I use only data. Saini i edit my post with my manifest

Comment: What request are you sending to fcm?

Comment: I edit my post with the json parameter

Comment: do you get a success result?

Comment: Yes absolutly. My push notification works when the app is launched but not when is closed.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but what do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"? When the app is backgrounded/not active, the expected behavior for a notification is that it shows in the system tray. Does it not show in the system tray for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FCM does support notifications when app is closed. Your code seems to be OK, so I suppose battery economizers (or power savers) can kill your notifications. I had such problems on my Asus Zenfone, also they were reported in cases of using Huawei and Xiaomi. Just disable them or add your app in exception list, if there is one. Also there is a new power-saving mode in recent releases of Android, try to disable it too.

Comment: Ok I use a Huawei. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @yozzy, did it solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you I just test on a HTC and it works great. Do you an idea to solve this issue on phone not compatible ?

Comment: @yozzy, unfortunately I don't know, how to struggle against Huawei and other brands' powersaving utilities, but there are some remarks about Android 6.0 Dose power saver: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html and https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message can help you

Comment: you can visit this blog https://darshanthakkar1569.medium.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-for-android-d61ae7866b83