# Android: Notification not delivered to user using Firebase Cloud Message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use `Firebase Cloud Message` at the first time . I connected my app to `Firebase` and used [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#9) but there isn't any notification

Here is my code .

in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

In `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService`

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService  {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
private static final String FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC = "football";
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "FCM Token: " + token);

    // Once a token is generated, we subscribe to topic.
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
            .subscribeToTopic(FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC);
   }
}
```

In `MyFirebaseMessagingService`

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFMService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Handle data payload of FCM messages.
    Log.d(TAG, "FCM Message Id: " + remoteMessage.getMessageId());
    Log.d(TAG, "FCM Notification Message: " +
            remoteMessage.getNotification());
    Log.d(TAG, "FCM Data Message: " + remoteMessage.getData());
   }
}
```

And here is the messages that I sent in `Firebase Console` .

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260833/firebase-push-notification)

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a notification then it will show on notification tray.
now when your on message received method called it will only prints log.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request 
   code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = 
    RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
    NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

    .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)

            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID() /* ID of notification */, 
    notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: What is the notificationID() ?

Comment: you can pass 0 in this time

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work . Is there something wrong in my code ?

Comment: try to debug and see on message received method called or not

Comment: Okay I will try

Comment: Target Estimate in Firebase Console became 1 (me) but it didn't appear .